# Whats the main difference between the coffees named "Kopi O Kosong", "Kopi" and "Kopi Peng"?

Tags: beans, coffee-culture, coffee-machines, flavored-coffee

How we will differentiate between the coffee that either is it Kopi O Kosong, Kopi or Kopi Peng as all are a form of black coffee?

Answer (score 1):

Hi kopi o kosong is just black coffee without sugar, kopi is coffee with condensed milk and kopi peng is just kopi with ice

Answer (score 1):

Singaporean traditional coffee culture uses a variety of terms originating from Malay, Hokkien, Cantonese etc. Here are the usual terms for kopi:

| Term | Meaning | Etymology |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Kopi | Coffee with condensed milk and sugar | Malay *kopi* |
| [Kopi]-O | Without milk | Hokkien 乌 |
| [Kopi]-C | With evaporated milk | English [***C**arnation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnation_(brand)) |
| [Kopi] Kosong | Without sugar | Malay *kosong* |
| [Kopi] Siew Dai | Less sugar | Cantonese 少底 |
| [Kopi] Ga Dai | More sugar | Cantonese 加底 |
| [Kopi] Peng | Iced | Hokkien 冰 |
| [Kopi] Gau | Strong coffee | Hokkien 厚 |
| [Kopi] Por | Weak coffee | Hokkien 薄 |
| Yuenyeung | Half kopi half tea | Cantonese 鴛鴦 |

Source: http://www.mysmu.edu/faculty/jacklee/singlish_K.htm